# I am getting DataSource Not Supported when using DataSouceBuilder

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring-Batch (and Spring in general), and have been following on line documentation to teach myself what I need to do this task. I am trying to connect to a DB2 database.

If I declare the DB2 connection with XML like this:

```
    <bean id="wcs_dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1/DEV" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass5" />
</bean>
```

Then load it in my code like so:

```
@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Product> databaseItemReader() {             
        ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context-datasource.xml");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("wcs_dataSource");
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();

        JdbcCursorItemReader<Product> result = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Product>();
        result.setDataSource(dataSource);
        result.setSql(sqlString);
        result.setRowMapper(new ProductRowMapper());
        return result;
    }
```

It works perfectly. How ever I would like to use the DataSourceBuilder like the examples show so ultimately I would like to get to :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="DEV.datasource")
public DataSource Wcs_DataSource(){
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

But for some reason that does not work. I get

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found

I have also tried:

```
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {               
    DataSourceBuilder DSBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();   
    DSBuilder.url("jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1/DEV");
    DSBuilder.username("user");
    DSBuilder.password("password");
    DSBuilder.driverClassName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    DriverManagerDataSource result = (DriverManagerDataSource) DSBuilder.build();
    return result;      
}
```

And I get the same error. If I run it in the debugger, I can see that the error happens on the .build().

I am sure I am missing something easy, but I can not figure it out.

Comment: First off all the `build` returns a `DataSource` and this should be the type you return, don't cast it to a `DriverManagerDataSource` as that will fail. To use the `DataSourceBuilder` you need to have `commons-dbcp`, or `tomcat-jdbc` or `hikaricp` on your classpath else it won't work. I you don't have one of those you will get the message as you get. Another thing do you really need a custom namespace (`DEV.datasource`) why not simply use the default?

Comment: Namespace will be because there will be more than one datasource. This is the documentation I was following for that is:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

I have tried it without and with DriverManagerDataSource  with the same results. There was another howto I was looking that that used that So I tried it (was grasping for straws by that point), but it did not help. I have removed it since posting this. 

BUT adding commons-dbcp to my dependencies did work! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

M. Deinum answered it. I was missing commons-dbcp from my dependencies! I figured it was something easy like that.

> To use the DataSourceBuilder you need to have *commons-dbcp*, or
>   *tomcat-jdbc* or *hikaricp* on your classpath else it won't work. I you
>   don't have one of those you will get the message as you get.

Comment: Hi, commons-dbcp does not worked for me , however hikaricp solved the issue

Answer (score 20):

In my case, add **spring-boot-starter-jdbc** dependency works:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Adding org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa helps too.

Comment: Thanks this was it, it needed additional jars to initialize specific data source