# Error when create DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I get a spring boot application and trying create a DataSource bean defined by Java configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "dsBD") @Primary
public DataSource dsBD() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create()
    .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/‌​database?autoReconne‌​ct=true")
    .username("‌​root")
    .password("mysql")
    .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Drive‌​r")
    .build();
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcBD") @Autowired
public JdbcTemplate jdbcBD(@Qualifier("dsBD") DataSource dsBD) {
  return new JdbcTemplate(dsBD);
}
```

But when starting application, I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.getType(DataSourceBuilder.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:69) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.package.DatabaseConfig.dsBD(DatabaseConfig.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.package.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ac56d75a.CGLIB$dsBD$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.package.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ac56d75a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$159befb3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.package.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ac56d75a.dsBD(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You did not configure the datasource, it looks like. Or there is a problem in your config, it's hard to tell since you don't show us the neither the code nor the config.

Comment: Hi @M. Prokhorov, this is my config code for the DataSource 
`
 @Bean(name = "dsBD")
 @Primary
 public DataSource dsBD() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true").username("root")
    .password("mysql").driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").build();
 }

 @Bean(name = "jdbcBD")
 @Autowired
 public JdbcTemplate jdbcBD(@Qualifier("dsBD") DataSource dsBD) {
  return new JdbcTemplate(dsBD);
 }
`

Comment: That is fine and all, but can we have all of that in the question itself?

Comment: I got error when run the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting DataSource Not Supported when using DataSouceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790924/i-am-getting-datasource-not-supported-when-using-datasoucebuilder)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms to use DataSourceBuilder you need to have one of the following on your classpath:

1. *COMMONS-DBCP*
2. *TOMCAT-JDBC*
3. *HIKARICP*

Otherwise you will get an `IllegalStateException` for no supported type, as you get now.

Comment: Thanks lazarov. I added common-dbcp library and run.