# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

Spring boot can't create my Postgres datasource. The error is starting here:

```
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.getType(DataSourceBuilder.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
```

Ultimately throwing error:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found
```

I've built Spring Apps using xml configuration and Maven, but Spring Boot and Gradle are new to me. I'm used to `@Autowire` pulling the datasource from the config file. Based on some SO answers, I added a database config class:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();

    }

}
```

I'm trying to autowire the datasource to my JDBC implementation:

```
@Component
public class JDBCRegionNameDAO implements RegionNameDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public JDBCRegionNameDAO (DataSource dataSource)  {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

My application.properties, I've checked my postgres credentials, and ensured the service is running:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/world_builder
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

My build.gradle, from what I've looked at, it seems that I have everything here that I need, but the error being thrown above suggests I'm missing something:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'group.group'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies { 

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'

    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')    

    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting DataSource Not Supported when using DataSouceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790924/i-am-getting-datasource-not-supported-when-using-datasoucebuilder)

Answer (score 11):

The issue was with the     `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')` dependency. Changing this to the following solved the issue for me:    `compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.6.RELEASE'`

Possibly the `jdbc` package or one of its dependencies is no longer supported.

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794085/1053362

Adding `commons-dbcp2` as a dependency worked for me.

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
...
```